# How to change the query to remain only leaf nodes

Tags: postgresql

I have table with the following data:

```
 id | parent_id |   short_name   
----+-----------+----------------
  6 |         5 | cpu
  7 |         5 | ram
 14 |         9 | tier-a
 15 |         9 | rfc1918
 16 |         9 | tolerant
 17 |         9 | nononymous
 13 |        12 | cloudstack
  5 |        13 | virtualmachine
  8 |        13 | volume
  9 |        13 | ipv4
  3 |           | domain
  4 |           | account
 12 |           | vdc
(13 rows)
```

with recursive query it looks like this:

```
with recursive tree ( id, parent_id, short_name, deep_name ) as (
select resource_type_id, parent_resource_type_id, short_name, short_name::text 
from resource_type
where parent_resource_type_id is null
union all
select rt.resource_type_id as id, rt.parent_resource_type_id, rt.short_name,
 tree.deep_name || '.' || rt.short_name
from tree, resource_type rt
where tree.id = rt.parent_resource_type_id
)
select * from tree;

 id | parent_id |   short_name   |             deep_name             
----+-----------+----------------+-----------------------------------
  4 |           | account        | account
  3 |           | domain         | domain
 12 |           | vdc            | vdc
 13 |        12 | cloudstack     | vdc.cloudstack
  9 |        13 | ipv4           | vdc.cloudstack.ipv4
  5 |        13 | virtualmachine | vdc.cloudstack.virtualmachine
  8 |        13 | volume         | vdc.cloudstack.volume
  6 |         5 | cpu            | vdc.cloudstack.virtualmachine.cpu
 15 |         9 | rfc1918        | vdc.cloudstack.ipv4.rfc1918
 17 |         9 | nononymous     | vdc.cloudstack.ipv4.nononymous
 16 |         9 | tolerant       | vdc.cloudstack.ipv4.tolerant
 14 |         9 | tier-a         | vdc.cloudstack.ipv4.tier-a
  7 |         5 | ram            | vdc.cloudstack.virtualmachine.ram
(13 rows)
```

**How to fix the query so in result I get only leafs?** eg. `vdc.cloudstack.volume` row and no `vdc`, `vdc.cloudstack` rows

**UPD**
rows with no children

Comment: Please do not extend the scope of your question once you have an answer to your original problem. If the answer results in a new question, then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You might want to link back to this question to expand the context of the new question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: fixed. I did [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51964031/4632019)

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the rows where `deep_name` has a superstring somewhere else in the table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (...)
SELECT * FROM tree AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM tree AS t2
   WHERE t2.deep_name
         LIKE t1.deep_name || '.%'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laurenz Albe's answer give me an idea. I think it would be more efficient to count childs than working with strings.

My solution is:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (...)
SELECT * FROM tree t1 
WHERE not EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tree t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.parent_id  );
```

Answer (score 0):

A leaf node is a child which is not itself a parent.

If all you want is a list of leaf notes you don't need the recursive CTE, you just need an anti-join in your preferred format.

If (as I imagine you do) you need the deep_name, I would anti-join the result of the recursive CTE to the raw source table on id = parent_id.

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (...)
SELECT * FROM tree AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM resource_type AS t2
                  WHERE t2.parent_resource_type_id = t1.id);
```

Comment: I need recursive, because leaf name should contain full path. Notice: `vdc.cloudstack.volume`

Comment: My edit and your comment happened at the same time.  I think you already got there with your own answer, but you don't need to execute the recursive CTE twice - may be quicker to anti-join on the raw table depending on the database

Comment: I tried that. The explain is similar. The difference only in naming.

Comment: I think it's more than just naming as far as the optimiser's concerned, but I'm sure with 13 rows it's practically moot.  With 13M rows I think you'd notice.