# Which query is faster?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I get two answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51963027/4632019), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955489/4632019). But I still do not know which is efficient. Here is `explain` of both:

explain for `my` query:

```
 Hash Anti Join  (cost=136.09..138.49 rows=1 width=556)
   Hash Cond: (t1.id = t2.parent_id)
   CTE tree
     ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.14..132.81 rows=101 width=556)
           ->  Index Scan using resource_type_idx_parent_resource_type_id on resource_type  (cost=0
                 Index Cond: (parent_resource_type_id IS NULL)
           ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.33..12.26 rows=10 width=556)
                 Hash Cond: (rt.parent_resource_type_id = tree.id)
                 ->  Seq Scan on resource_type rt  (cost=0.00..11.30 rows=130 width=524)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=0.20..0.20 rows=10 width=36)
                       ->  WorkTable Scan on tree  (cost=0.00..0.20 rows=10 width=36)
   ->  CTE Scan on tree t1  (cost=0.00..2.02 rows=101 width=556)
   ->  Hash  (cost=2.02..2.02 rows=101 width=4)
         ->  CTE Scan on tree t2  (cost=0.00..2.02 rows=101 width=4)
```

`Laurenz Albe` answer:

```
 Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=132.81..388.39 rows=100 width=556)
   Join Filter: (t2.deep_name ~~ (t1.deep_name || '.%'::text))
   CTE tree
     ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.14..132.81 rows=101 width=556)
           ->  Index Scan using resource_type_idx_parent_resource_type_id on resource_type  (cost=0
                 Index Cond: (parent_resource_type_id IS NULL)
           ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.33..12.26 rows=10 width=556)
                 Hash Cond: (rt.parent_resource_type_id = tree.id)
                 ->  Seq Scan on resource_type rt  (cost=0.00..11.30 rows=130 width=524)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=0.20..0.20 rows=10 width=36)
                       ->  WorkTable Scan on tree  (cost=0.00..0.20 rows=10 width=36)
   ->  CTE Scan on tree t1  (cost=0.00..2.02 rows=101 width=556)
   ->  CTE Scan on tree t2  (cost=0.00..2.02 rows=101 width=32)
```

The diff beetwen them:

```
--- CTE Scan on tree  (cost=132.81..134.83 rows=101 w (Selection)
+++ (clipboard)
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
- Hash Anti Join  (cost=136.09..138.49 rows=1 width=556)
-   Hash Cond: (t1.id = t2.parent_id)
+ Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=132.81..388.39 rows=100 width=556)
+   Join Filter: (t2.deep_name ~~ (t1.deep_name || '.%'::text))
    CTE tree
      ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.14..132.81 rows=101 width=556)
            ->  Index Scan using resource_type_idx_parent_resource_type_id on resource_type  (cost=0
@@ -10,5 +10,4 @@
                  ->  Hash  (cost=0.20..0.20 rows=10 width=36)
                        ->  WorkTable Scan on tree  (cost=0.00..0.20 rows=10 width=36)
    ->  CTE Scan on tree t1  (cost=0.00..2.02 rows=101 width=556)
-   ->  Hash  (cost=2.02..2.02 rows=101 width=4)
-         ->  CTE Scan on tree t2  (cost=0.00..2.02 rows=101 width=4)
+   ->  CTE Scan on tree t2  (cost=0.00..2.02 rows=101 width=32)
```

**Which one of them is faster?** how to know that from explain results?

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on both.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE

Comment: The difference (if any) is not significant. The CTE only yields 100rows,and the(anti-) self join can be executed completely in memory. Stitching buffers. BTW: both the CTE and the ~~ operator could cause degradation on non-trivial volumes of data.`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is your friend.

Comment: It seems to me that the first version with Hash Anti-join would be slightly better than the Nested Loop.